# Record count for view in graph

Tags: acumatica

I have a graph for a simple master/detail maintenance screen.  Master data is shown in the top form and detail in the grid at the bottom.  Detail rows can be deleted.

I would like to write some code to delete the master record when the last detail record is deleted.  I will also need to do other processing as each row is deleted, but I can handle that.  I am planning to do it in the RowDeleted handler.

My question is: Can I access the count of active rows in the view without having to run through a loop to count them?  I can't do a select from the database because they have not been saved yet.  I have an excerpt of the graph below.  What is the easiest way to detect that the last detail row has been deleted?

```
    public PXSelect<EDASN> ASN;

    public PXSelectJoin<EDASNShipment,
        LeftJoin<SOShipment, On<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<EDASNShipment.shipmentNbr>>,
        LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<EDASNShipment.shipmentNbr>>,
        LeftJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>>>>>,
        Where<EDASNShipment.aSNNbr, Equal<Current<EDASN.aSNNbr>>>> ASNShipment;

        protected virtual void EDASNShipment_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        EDASNShipment row = ASNShipment.Current;
        EDASN asn = this.ASN.Current;
        // need to determine if any shipments left on ASN
        // can I access a "count" of active rows from the ASNShipment view cache
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.  I just did a search of the cache and if it comes back null, the last shipment has been deleted.

```
    protected virtual void EDASNShipment_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        EDASNShipment row = ASNShipment.Current;
        EDASNShipment asnShipments = this.ASNShipment.Search<EDASNShipment.aSNNbr>(row.ASNNbr);
        // Remove ASN record if no more shipments
        if (asnShipments == null)
        {
            EDASN asn = this.ASN.Current;
            this.ASN.Delete(asn);
            this.Persist();
        }
```